# Pesquisa Mysql com input erro

Tags: php, mysqli, undefined

O pesquisa ta retornando uma notícia e ta retornando todos os nomes do banco de dados:

"Notice: Undefined index: pesquisar_nome" no conexao.php.

```
if(isset($_POST["acao"])){
    if($_POST["acao"] == "pesquisar_nome"){
        pesquisarCliente();
    }
}

/* Pesquisar Cliente*/
function pesquisarCliente(){
    $bd = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projeto_ap2");    
    $pesquisaNome = $_POST['pesquisar_nome'];
    $sqlPesquisarNome = "SELECT nome FROM cliente WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisaNome%'";
    $resultado = $bd->query($sqlPesquisarNome);

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        echo "Nomes relacionados: ".$rows['nome']."</br>";
    }
}
```

No formulário de pesquisa:

```
<form action="../conexao.php" method="POST">        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Pesquisar:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nomeCliente" value="" placeholder="Digite um nome..."/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="acao" value="pesquisar_nome" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" name="Pesquisar" /></td>
            </tr>        
        </tbody>
</form></br></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando obter o `input` de name "pesquisar_nome":

```
$pesquisaNome = $_POST['pesquisar_nome'];
```

Sendo que o name que você está passando é "nomeCliente"

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 

O seu problema está na seguinte linha:

```php
$pesquisaNome = $_POST['pesquisar_nome'];
```

Não existe nenhum input cujo name seja `pesquisar_nome`,   a solução é trocar para `nomeCliente`, que é o name do input de texto que receberá o nome do cliente. Tente modificar a linha em questão para:

```php
$pesquisaNome = $_POST['nomeCliente'];
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!